# parsing of javascript objects using python

Tags: python, parsing

friends!
I'm starting to learn python. I have a problem with obtaining the required value from javascript text. Here is the code, which I managed to download from website:

```
[<script src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAOjFUxXImJbfYejRUbw0-uBSoJppdodHXaiZe2O5Byw3T7kzYihSys_Exmi235-oDCy6xEhVelBMhBQ" type="text/javascript"></script>, <script type="text/javascript">
    var map_shop = null;
    var marker_shop     = null;

    function google_maps_shop_initialize() 
    {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
        {
            map_shop = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas_shop"));
            point_center = new GLatLng(51.6663267, 39.1898874);             

            marker_shop = new GMarker(point_center);
            map_shop.addOverlay(marker_shop);

            map_shop.setCenter(point_center, 13);           

            //Create new Tile Layer
            var gTileUrlTemplate = '//mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@121,transit|vm:1&hl=ru&opts=r&x={X}&y={Y}&z={Z}';
            var tileLayerOverlay = new GTileLayerOverlay(
                new GTileLayer(null, null, null, {
                    tileUrlTemplate: gTileUrlTemplate,
                    isPng:true,
                    opacity:1
                })
            );
            map_shop.addOverlay(tileLayerOverlay);
        }
    }
    google_maps_shop_initialize();
</script>]
```

I want to print only one line from text, which contains coordinates `point_center = new GLatLng(51.6663267, 39.1898874);`

I'm trying decide it using re module, but the problem is that number of line may vary and I get empty output with this  code:

```
   if re.match("point_center = new GLatLng", line):
            print (line)
```

Desirable output looks like this:

```
51.6663267, 39.1898874
```

Comment: so...please share what you have tried. If you have not tried anything, make an attempt

Comment: You could parse the JS and traverse the AST to find this. But a simple regex will probably do. https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If the Javascript is .txt format then you can simply do this:

`from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "point_center = new GLatLng" in line:
             linestring = line
             linestring = linestring[26:]
             linestring = make_tuple(linestring)`

Your output should be a tuple.